# Please Noindex 'Recently Active XXX,' 'Newest XXX,' etc

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, google, seo, noindex

I was recently looking for an old post on gaming.stackexchange.com, and one of the things I remembered was that the game *"SingStar"* was mentioned.  Thus, I typed ["singstar site:gaming.stackexchange.com"](http://www.google.com/search?q=singstar+site%3Agaming.stackexchange.com) into google, expecting to only see a dozen posts or so.  Instead, I was greeted with hundreds of PAGES of results:

[image]

Only one of the shown results is an actual post.

Having the tag-wiki page indexed makes sense, and *maybe* the tag-FAQs.  However, the tag search-pages are just noise, especially the ones which combine *Tag1* + *Tag2*, for every possible combination with a question.  I think these should be marked with a [noindex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noindex).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't a bad idea at all, starting with the next build we'll be returning a 404 to crawlers looking at **multiple** tag `/questions/tagged` pages so we're not spamming the result list with duplicates.  So (related to tags) you'll start seeing 2 top results, the wiki and the list of questions for that tag (assuming we're a popular result, of course).

Now keep in mind that this won't be an instant fix, it'll take a while for google to re-crawl these and remove them from their index, but it will happen.

Comment: Has this been done yet?  I'm still seeing these results on google.

Comment: @BlueRaja - it has, but it'll take some time for it to drop them from the index...since it's a header and not a `robots.txt` block (which is far more immediate)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you end up choosing this method of blocking rather than the more usual `noindex`?  Doesn't returning lots of (false) 404's hurt your SEO?